# Загрузка начинки приложения при первом запуске с сервера

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый вечер.

Мало очень инфы в Интернете на эту тему. Напишите, пожалуйста, небольшую инструкцию, можно в общем, а лучше конкретно.

Например, в приложении у меня 50 картинок, умноженное на количество разных экранов айфонов и айпадов. Хочу, чтоб при первом запуске приложение определяло модель и закачивало в приложение группу картинок с сервера под этот конкретно экран.

Пролейте свет, спасибо.

Вообще не кривя душок надеялся получить такой формат ответа:

1)Как выбрать сервер (надежный, удобный)?

2)Как закинуть на сервер картинки?

3)Как выкачать с сервера картинки?(кодик)

4)Возможно ли скачивать папки с картинками прямо в приложение как будто они сначала там были?

5)Как сделать стандартный индикатор? (кодик)

6)Как скачивать картинки при запуске из ходя из разрешения экрана?

Вот такая краткая инструкция выручила бы меня и будущее поколение!!!))

Answer (score 1):

Где-нибудь глобально определяете:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_4 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )480 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)667) < DBL_EPSILON)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)736) < DBL_EPSILON)
```

Там, где нужно обратить внимание на тип устройства:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_4)
{

}
else if (IS_IPHONE_5)
{

}
```

и т.д.

P.S. [[@AlessandroDP](/users/12810/alessandrodp)](/users/12810/alessandrodp) прав, гуглится элементарно. Учитесь пользоваться сначала поиском.

Comment: Ой, похоже я не на то акцентировал, мне нужно как загрузить на сервер картинки, а потом их выгружать при старте приложения?  Вот это плохо гуглиться!

Comment: @SergeyXcode, ой лукавите))) Быть того не может - ищите на английском, если всё так плохо... Хотя сразу стоило так делать)

Comment: @SergeyXcode, разбивайте задачи, Ваш вопрос слишком комплексный.
Сначала гуглите как закачивать файлы на сервер, после решения задачи гуглите как их оттуда скачать, потом используйте указанный ответ для того чтобы скачивать те которые подходят устройству. Иначе вопрос звучит как "как написать приложение", ответить на него - дольше чем написать приложение

Answer (score 1):

У вас при запуске появляется РутКонтроллер (он же ВьюКонтроллер). Скачайте AFNetworking 2.0, подключите, создайте метод который тянет картинки с сервера, а на ВьюКонтроллере втулите анимационный спиннер. Это как один из множества вариантов.

Другой вариант как в других мобильных приложениях: показываются "плейсхолдеры", и пока юзер клипает глазами постепенно подгружаются картинки без всяких спинбаров и т.д.

Я бы выбрал второй. Т.к. и проложение запущено и интерфейс отобразился, а то что через пару сек подгрузится картинка (в зависимости от ответа сервака и размера картинок, что нужно тоже учесть и желательно иметь превью для картинок) меня мало волнует, т.к. я уже могу серфить по самому приложению.

Comment: Спасибо, лучший ответ!
Вообще не кривя душок надеялся получить такой формат ответа:
1)Как выбрать сервер (надежный, удобный)?
2)Как закинуть на сервер картинки?
3)Как выкачать с сервера картинки?(кодик)
4)Возможно ли скачивать папки с картинками прямо в приложение как будто они сначала там были?
5)Как сделать стандартный индикатор? (кодик)
6)Как скачивать картинки при запуске из ходя из разрешения экрана?

Вот такая краткая инструкция выручила бы меня и будущее поколение!!!))

Answer (score 0):

> мало очень инфы в интернете на эту
> тему

Да вы, по-видимому, смеетесь над нами - а про вот такое не слышали???????

```
[UIScreen mainScreen]
[UIDevice currentDevice]
```

Comment: Меня не этот момент интересует, а как подгружать с  сервера?

Comment: Эээ, гет/пост запросы изучите что ли, для начала, или хоть что то почитайте, прежде чем такОООе спрашивать))

+ Куча либ по работе с апи. 

++ http://bit.ly/1BuGH6I

+++ http://bit.ly/1MEHXHP